# Find element inside tree and change it's parents' properties values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree

I want to find an element inside a tree by its property value and then move back to the beginning of the tree and set `isExpanded` property of each of element's parents to `true` using JS.

So I have this object:

```
elementsArray = [
  {
    name: 'test_1',
    isExpanded: false,
    expandElements: [
      {
        name: 'test_1_1',
        isExpanded: false,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_1_1_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_1_1_2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'test_1_2',
        isExpanded: false,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_1_2_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_1_2_2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'test_2',
    isExpanded: false,
    expandElements: [
      {
        name: 'test_2_1',
        isExpanded: false,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_2_1_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_2_1_2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'test_2_2',
        isExpanded: false,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_2_2_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_2_2_2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find the element, which has property `name: 'test_2_2_1'` and set `isExpanded` property of each of its parents to true.

How it should work:

- call a method `expandParentElements(elementsArray, 'test_2_2_1')`
- `elementsArray` changed to:

```
elementsArray = [
  {
    name: 'test_1',
    isExpanded: false,
    expandElements: [
      {
        name: 'test_1_1',
        isExpanded: false,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_1_1_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_1_1_2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'test_1_2',
        isExpanded: false,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_1_2_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_1_2_2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'test_2',
    isExpanded: **true**,
    expandElements: [
      {
        name: 'test_2_1',
        isExpanded: false,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_2_1_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_2_1_2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'test_2_2',
        isExpanded: **true**,
        expandElements: [
          {
            name: 'test_2_2_1'
          },
          {
            name: 'test_2_2_2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

By now i've managed to only recursively move inside tree and find proper element. Here how it looks like:

```
let expandParentElements = (array, searchName) => {
  return array.map(item => {
    if (item.name === searchName) {
      return item
    } else if (item.expandElements) {
      return expandParentElements(item.expandElements, searchName)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would be nice if you provide some code showing what you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: @RDev, thanks for the tip. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that sets `isExpanded` on the path to the item. The item itself (e.g. when it is has subitems) will *not* get `isExpanded` set to true.

This function does also not clear the `isExpanded` values that might have already been set to `true` before calling the function.

```js
const expandParentElements = (array, searchName) =>
    array && array.some(item => item.name === searchName ||
        expandParentElements(item.expandElements, searchName) && (item.isExpanded = true)
    );

// Sample data from question
const elementsArray = [{name: 'test_1',isExpanded: false,expandElements: [{name: 'test_1_1',isExpanded: false,expandElements: [{name: 'test_1_1_1'},{name: 'test_1_1_2'}]},{name: 'test_1_2',isExpanded: false,expandElements: [{name: 'test_1_2_1'},{name: 'test_1_2_2'}]}]},{name: 'test_2',isExpanded: false,expandElements: [{name: 'test_2_1',isExpanded: false,expandElements: [{name: 'test_2_1_1'},{name: 'test_2_1_2'}]},{name: 'test_2_2',isExpanded: false,expandElements: [{name: 'test_2_2_1'},{name: 'test_2_2_2'}]}]}];

expandParentElements(elementsArray, "test_2_2_1");
console.log(elementsArray);
```

You may want to also use a function to collapse all, i.e. set all `isExpanded` to `false`:

```
const collapseAll = (array) =>
    array.filter(item => item.expandElements)
         .forEach(item => (item.isExpanded = false, collapseAll(item.expandElements)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elementsArray.forEach(element => {

  let updateParent =  element.expandElements.reduce(((prevFound, expandElement) => {

      let found = expandElement.expandElements.some(obj => obj.name === "test_1_1_1")
      expandElement.isExpanded = found
      return prevFound || found

  }), false)

  element.isExpanded = updateParent

})
```